# Swift - How to use CodingKeys to map an Int to a custom enum?

Tags: json, swift, enums, decodable

I am loading in JSON which has integers that I wish to map to an enum

```
//Some JSON object
{
    "id": "....",
    "name": "Some Locomotive"
    "livery": 1,
    "generation": 1
    // other variables
}
```

I can load this JSON in using:

```
struct Locomotive: Codable {
    var id, name: String
    var generation: Int   
    // var livery: Int -- Replace this with my own enum (below)
    var livery: Livery?

    private enum CodingKeys: CodingKey {
        case id, name, generation
        case livery = "livery" // complains of raw value issue
    }
}
```

Currently both the generaiton and livery are just Integers; but to make coding easier for me I wish to use map the livery Integer to an enum; so rather than remembering 1 = green, etc; I can just say .green

But I am have trouble mapping the key livery to my enum.

> Enum case cannot have a raw value if the enum does not have a raw type

But I'm sure it does; I've defined the raw value in the enum as private though;

```
enum Livery : Codable {
    case green, red, blue, yellow
}

extension Livery {

    private enum RawValue: Int, Codable, CaseIterable {
        case green = 1, red, yellow, blue
    }

    private enum CodingKeys: Int, CodingKey {
        case green, red, blue, yellow
    }

init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        let key = container.allKeys.first

        switch key {
        case .green:
            self = .green
        case .red:
            self = .red
        case .yellow:
            self = .yellow
        case .blue:
            self = .blue

        default:
            throw DecodingError.dataCorrupted(
                DecodingError.Context(
                    codingPath: container.codingPath,
                    debugDescription: "Error -- Unabled to decode."
                )
            )
        }
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()

        switch self {
        case .green:
            try container.encode(RawValue.green)
        case .red:
            try container.encode(RawValue.red)
        case .yellow:
            try container.encode(RawValue.yellow)
        case .blue:
            try container.encode(RawValue.blue)
        }

    }
}
```

The above enum decodes the raw value and encodes it.

However, I am unable to map the Livery in the parent struct to this enum and I'm wondering how I can do this?

...

I think I have to implement `init(from decoder: Decoder)` and `encode(to encoder: Encoder)` to this structure too -- especially if I want to save my data to JSON in the future; but I am not sure.

Thus, my query is - how do you map an Integer provided by the JSON to a custom enum for both saving (encoding) and loading (decoding).

With thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simplify your code quite a lot, all you need is the below code. By saying that your enum is of type Int swift can synthesise the correct decoding code

```
struct Locomotive: Codable {
    var id, name: String
    var generation: Int
    var livery: Livery?
}

enum Livery: Int, Codable {
    case green = 1, red, blue, yellow
}
```

Comment: That worked -- I thought I had to decode and map each value manually; thanks!

Comment: when it comes to saving it to disk (json file); will it still keep the Integers; or do I still need to map it?

Comment: Nice one, I also was trying to manually encode and decode and struggled to do that correctly, but actually it has so simple solution just to conform to Codable protocol. Thank you :))

Answer (score 4):

The issue is that you declared your `Locomotive.CodingKeys` `enum` incorrectly. All `CodingKey` compliant enums need to have a `rawValue`, but you declared `CodingKeys` with no `rawValue`. Giving it a `String` `rawValue` solves your problem.

```
struct Locomotive: Codable {
    var id, name: String
    var generation: Int
    // var livery: Int -- Replace this with my own enum (below)
    var livery: Livery?

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id, name, generation, livery
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll give it a go -- maybe I just tried to overcomplicate it.

Comment: It complained that the data was invalid format.    I made sure that both codingkeys has a string key  `private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {`

Comment: I think the coding keys or the `init(from decoder: Decoder)` in the Livery enum  is causing an issue when I try to map it